# Return the position (column) of the maximum value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello I've been trying to figure out how to return position (column number) of the maximum value of a list (row of numbers).

Please see attached as an example. I want to return 'Rate 1' since the max is 52,204 -- I know I can use VLOOKUP and also INDEX and MATCH but I don't think they work in this example and I don't want to switch the rows/columns.

Please point me in the right direction and I will keep at it.

Thanks

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
=index(a1:c1,match(max(a2:c2),a2:c2,0))
```

adjusting ranges to suit.

Find the relative position of the max in row 2 (=1) and return the corresponding element in row 1 (=Rate1).